# conditional porbability or not?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I have this exercise

"Let $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables, with $$X \geq 0$$ e $$Y \sim \exp (\lambda)$$ . Then prove that $$Pr(Y>X)=E(e^{-\lambda X})$$ "

I have tried to use the conditional probability :

$$Pr (Y>X | Y=X) = \int e^ {-\lambda X} P\circ X^{-1}\, dx$$ but I do not know that it's okay....ideas?

thank you very much

Comment: Use that $\mathbb{P}(Y > X) = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y > t) f_X(t) \,\mathrm{d}t,$ where $f_X(t)$ is the probability density function of $X$.

Comment: ok thanks! But I can say that $$P(Y>t)= 1 - P(Y<t)$$ ?

Comment: Definitely, but use $\mathbb{P}(Y > t) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(Y \le t)$ to be precise.