# How can I use the conditional probability?

Tags: statistics

I have this exercise :

"Let X and Y independent random variables, with $$ X\geq0 $$ and $$ Y\sim exp(\lambda) $$. Then prove that $$ P(Y>X) = E(e^{-\lambda X})$$ "

I rewrote this $$ E(e^{-\lambda X}) $$ as $$ \int e^{-\lambda X} P \circ X^{-1}\, dx $$ now, I want to try to do to become $$ P(Y>X) $$ the same. 
I thought about using the conditional probability, therefore ,
$$ P(Y>X | X=t) = \int P(Y>t) P \circ X^{-1}\, dx $$ ,  $$ P(Y>t)= 1- P(Y \leq t)  $$ and now $$ 1- P(Y \leq t) = 1 - (1- e^{-\lambda X}) $$ .

but I do not know if the procedure is right. can anyone help me?

thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [conditional porbability or not?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153135/conditional-porbability-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

Just observe that $$P(Y>X)=\int P(Y>X|X=x)f(x) dx\stackrel{X\perp Y}{=}\int P(Y>x)f(x) dx\\=\int e^{-\lambda x}f(x) dx =E(e^{-\lambda X})$$

Answer (score 0):

$$P\left(Y>X\right)=\int P\left(Y>X\mid X=x\right)f_{X}\left(x\right)dx=$$$$\int P\left(Y>x\right)f_{X}\left(x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}f_{X}\left(x\right)dx=\mathbb{E}e^{-\lambda X}$$

The second equality is a consequence of independence.